# wp_enqueue_script() no longer working in my function.php file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

We developed/launched a website over the summer that used a custom js script to add swatches to slider images.

All was working well, until recently we noticed that the slider swatches were no longer appearing. Digging deeper I noticed that the custom js file created is no longer being added to the header of our site. Here is the coding we have in our functions.php file, which worked when we launched the site, as well as months after until recently:

```
function bd_slider_script() {
  if(is_front_page()){

    wp_enqueue_script("jquery");


    wp_enqueue_script(
        'slider-swatches',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/slider_swatches.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '05122014',
        true
    );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bd_slider_script', 11 );
```

Did the recent version of WordPress update this script? Or is there something I'm missing?? This worked for months, now all of the sudden it does not....

Any help is much appreciate!

Comment: Have you upgraded WordPress or the theme that you're using?

Comment: WordPress and all plugins are updated to the most recent version. For this site we used Whiteboard as a framework, which is also the most recent version (no new version released since before we launched the site)

Comment: Your script is loaded in the footer

Comment: I believe that `slider_swatches` has a compatibility issue with the never version of jquery. The jquery versions shipped with wordpress does get updated in newer versions

Comment: As mentioned by @PieterGoosen, you are loading your script in the footer. The last parameter is whether to add it to the footer or not (default for this is FALSE).

Comment: Thank you! I was doing a browser search of the source code and finding no results for "slider_swatches". Checking manually (i.e. with my two eyes) I found it. Tested with the newest version of WP jquery the scripting still works. I found the issue to be CSS classes not assigning proper styling to display the swatches on each of the slides. Was able to update CSS and the swatches now appear! Thank you all for the responses!